# Why does MachineKey.Unprotect fail when the validationKey and encryptionKey are set to the auto-generated values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

After extracting the validation and encryption keys using the code below, I set the given keys in the web.config, hoping that anything produced with the auto-generated keys would decrypt with the statically-set keys.

This is however not the case, and so anything produced by `MachineKey.Protect` when the keys are auto-generated causes `MachineKey.Unprotect` to fail when the keys are set, despite the keys being theoretically identical.

I have:

- verified that `MachineKey.Unprotect` works fine for values produced by `MachineKey.Protect` when the keys are auto-generated,
- tried all of the `<machineKey>` `validation`, `encryption` and `compatibilityMode` values,
- verified that the code below returns the same keys regardless of whether they're set in the web.config or auto-generated (which is expected)

Unfortunately setting the keys to something new is not an option, as this would invalidate all existing tokens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code used to extract auto-generated keys:

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MachineKeySection section = (MachineKeySection) 
      ConfigurationManager.GetSection ("system.web/machineKey");

  BindingFlags flags = 
      BindingFlags.Instance | 
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
      BindingFlags.GetProperty;

  Func<string, byte[]> propertyReader = name => (byte[]) section
      .GetType ()
      .GetProperty (name, flags)
      .GetValue (section, null);

  string key = ConvertToHex (
    propertyReader ("DecryptionKeyInternal"));

  string iv = ConvertToHex (
    propertyReader ("ValidationKeyInternal"));
}

private string ConvertToHex (byte[] binary)
{
  return binary.Aggregate (
      new StringBuilder (), 
      (acc, c) => acc.AppendFormat ("{0:x2}", c), 
      acc => acc.ToString());
}
```

Code source: https://web.archive.org/web/20140329202612/http://aspnetresources.com/blog/how_to_read_auto_generated_machinekey